# How to preserve order of insertion in SciPy Sparse Matrix CSR_Matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'd like to preserve the order of insertion into a SciPy csr_matrix, however it seems to always sort it by row and then index:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> x = csr_matrix(([1,2,3],[[3,2,1],[5,2,1]]))
>>> print(x)
  (1, 1)    3
  (2, 2)    2
  (3, 5)    1
```

Anyway to keep the original sorting? What I want:

```
  (3, 5)    1
  (2, 2)    2
  (1, 1)    3
```

ETA: Figured out that inserting using the `data, indices, indptr` method preserves the order within row (still sorted by row but no longer by column indices). Whereas inserting by `data, indices` where indices is a 2D indices matrix is then sorted by both row and column indices.

Comment: 'csr' - compressed sparse row matrix.  Look at the `data, indices, indptr` style of inputs to see how this format stores the array.  Data has to be sorted by row.  This format is designed for efficient computation, not as some sort of general purpose data storage.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that inserting by `data, indices, indptr` preserves the order within row (still sorted by row but no longer by column indices). Whereas inserting by `data, indices` where `indices` is a 2D indices matrix is then sorted by both row and column indices. That's what I needed, thanks.

Comment: @narcissa just as a warning, there are several sparse operations which may sort the column indices in-place. Relying on them to be in the order of insertion will work until it doesn't.

Comment: If those arrays are correctly formatted (dtype etc), they are used as is in creating the matrix.  There is an inplace `sort` method, but I don't think that is normally invoked.  I don't know if sorting (or not) affects performance (e.g. for matrix multiplication).  I agree with @CJR that isn't a good idea to count on this order.  Sparse matrices, especially `csr` are designed for linear algebra operations, not specialized data storage.

Comment: @hpaulj There are several mkl functions that sort without warning when invoked and I think a couple of the scipy solvers might as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSR format stores data in a row-wise format (by marking out the places in the memory-contiguous data array where each row begins and ends). The information that you want does not exist in that format - part of the compression is to remove it.

If you need that ordering information you could leave it in COO format with the caveat that there are operations which result in COO matrices being sorted without warning. It may be best to store that information explicitly instead of implicitly (do scipy sparse matrices let you use structs in the data matrix?).